# Best way to test array of range values against an IF statement

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

as part of building a spreadsheet tool for my organisation, I need to baby proof as much as possible said tool, which means checking a few conditions before allowing a function to run. I have a version of the code running but I'm wondering if there's a way to optimise it.

In the code below I'm using a for loop to check if a row in Col B has an empty value while having some value in Col C,D,E or F on the same row.

If the condition is true at least once than then we stop the loop and alert user. If the array pass the check then we do something at the end of the loop.

Can we avoid the loop at all? How one would optimise the code?

I did some research but .every or .some don't seems to cut it given the array structure of a range of value in Google Apps Script.

Here's a code summary on the part I'm interested in :

```js
function myFunc() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      bench = sheet.getSheets()[0].getRange('B1:F14').getValues();
  
  for (var c = 0; c < bench.length; c++) {
    
    var check = bench[c];
    
    if (check[0] === '' && ((check[1] || check[2] || check[3] || check[4]) != '')) { // check if a row in Col B as an empty value while having a value in Col C,D,E or F
      
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("line " + (c + 1) + " has no company name");
      break;
      
    } else { // everything pitchy
      
      if (c == (bench.length - 1)) {
        
        //Function run normaly
        
      }
      
    }
    
  }
  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your code only when the previous data doesn't affect the subsequent data and you edit the data regardless of when the loop is interrupted.

In this case, you can simplify the appearance of your code by leaving the nested conditions as early as possible:

```
function myFunc() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var bench = sheet
    .getSheets()[0]
    .getRange('B1:F14')
    .getValues();
  var client = bench[1][0];

  if (client === '') {
    // check if client name is not empty
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('client is empty');
    return;
  }

  for (var c = 0; c < bench.length; c++) {
    var check = bench[c];

    if (
      check[0] === '' &&
      [check[1], check[2], check[3], check[4]].join('') !== ''
    ) {
      // check if a row in Col B as an empty value while having a value in Col C,D,E or F

      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('line ' + (c + 1) + ' has no company name');
      break;
    }
    // everything pitchy

    if (c == bench.length - 1) {
      // Function run normaly
    }
  }
}
```

Otherwise, it is better to check the data in advance and work with a valid array:

```
function myFunc() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var bench = sheet
    .getSheets()[0]
    .getRange('B1:F14')
    .getValues();
  var client = bench[1][0];

  if (client === '') {
    // check if client name is not empty
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('client is empty');
    return;
  }

  var chcker = bench
    .filter(function(check) {
      return (
        check[0] === '' &&
        [check[1], check[2], check[3], check[4]].join('') !== ''
      );
    })
    .map(function(_, i) {
      return 'line ' + (i + 1) + ' has no company name';
    });
  if (chcker.length) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert(chcker.join('\n'));
    return;
  }

  for (var c = 0; c < bench.length; c++) {
    if (c == bench.length - 1) {
      // Function run normaly
    }
  }
}
```

If you wan't loop all you can add the `findIndex` [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex#Polyfill)

```
var chcker = bench
    .findIndex(function(check) {
      return (
        check[0] === '' &&
        [check[1], check[2], check[3], check[4]].join('') !== ''
      );
    });
if(chcker !== -1) { // The data invalid
```

Comment: Hi @oshliaer, thank you so much for your time and the details (and bonus info). Your response is a bit more advanced than my current level so I needed some time to play around with it and understand what it was doing and how. 

Just so I'm sure I understand, in your first bits of code: you filter the object based on the condition and then you create a new array with all response that matches the condition. Lastly, if the chcker variable has some content you alert its content and stop the function. Is that correct?

Comment: @Flavien, it's true.

Comment: Awesome thank you for your answer and allowing me to learn a few new things in the process!

Answer (score 1):

"some" is the method. The condition would look something like

```
var condition = check[0] === ''  && check.slice(1).some(function(item) { return item != '';});
```

Comment: Thanks for that other way to write the condition in itself, it's neater indeed but it still needs the loop to iterate through all the row to check for the condition, or am I missing something?